# Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): this.props.Quko is not iterable

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I am facing this error when I am trying to set my state coming from Fetched API data using Redux actions to pass it to my component and using mapStateToProps in my use case. As it is visible that in my mapStateToProps I am getting the response **getAllQuestions** but as soon when It was called into setState the **questions**  state it is giving me an error even my actions are properly declared.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

import { Row, Col, Card, CardBody, Container, Button } from "reactstrap";
// Editable
import BootstrapTable from "react-bootstrap-table-next";
import cellEditFactory from "react-bootstrap-table2-editor";


import { fetchAllQuestions } from "../../redux/actions/questionActions";

import { connect } from "react-redux";

const columns = [
  {
    dataField: "sl no.",
    text: "S No.",
    formatter: (cell, row, rowIndex, formatExtraData) => {
      return rowIndex + 1;
    },
    sort: true,
  },
  {
    dataField: "text",
    text: "Question",
    sort: true,
  },
  {
    dataField: "answers",
    text: "Answers",
    sort: true,
  },
  {
    dataField: "tag",
    text: "Tag",
    sort: true,
  },
  {
    dataField: "keyword",
    text: "Keywords",
    sort: true,
  },

  {
    dataField: "gender",
    text: "Gender",
    sort: true,
  },
];

class EditableTables extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      breadcrumbItems: [
        { title: "Tables", link: "#" },
        { title: "Editable Tables", link: "#" },
      ],
      questions: [],
    };
  }

  async componentDidMount() {
    console.log('this.props.Questions', this.props.Quko);
    await this.props.getAllQuestions(this.props.user._id);
    await this.setState({ questions: [...this.props.Quko] });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <div className="page-content">
          <Container fluid>
            <Row>
              <Col xs={12}>
                <Card>
                  <CardBody>
                    <div className="table-responsive">
                      <BootstrapTable
                        keyField="id"
                        data={this.state.questions}
                        columns={columns}
                        cellEdit={cellEditFactory({ mode: "click" })}
                      />
                    </div>
                  </CardBody>
                </Card>
              </Col>
            </Row>
          </Container>
        </div>
      </React.Fragment>
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  console.log("state", state.question.questions.response);
  return {
    user: state.auth.user,
    Quko: state.question.questions.response,
  };
};

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
  return {
    getAllQuestions: (userId) => dispatch(fetchAllQuestions(userId)),
  };
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(EditableTables);
```

my actions file

```
export const fetchAllQuestions = (body, navigate) => async (dispatch) => {
  console.log("QUESTION BODY", body);
  const questionData = {
    customer_id: body,
  };
  console.log("QUESTION DATA", questionData);
  let response;
  try {
    await fetch(SERVER_URL + "/questions", {
      method: "POST", // *GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, etc.
      mode: "cors", // no-cors, *cors, same-origin
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        // 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
      },
      redirect: "follow", // manual, *follow, error
      body: JSON.stringify(questionData), // body data type must match "Content-Type" header
    })
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((data) => {
        console.log("Success:", data);
        if (data.statusCode === 200) {
          console.log("QUESTION FETCH SUCCESS");
          response = data;
          dispatch({
            type: actionTypes.GET_ALL_QUESTION,
            payload: {
              response,
            },
          });
        } else if (data.statusCode === 409) {
          console.log("QUESTION FETCH FAILED", data);
          response = data;
        }
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.error("Error:", error);
      });
    console.log("QUESTION FETCH RESPONSE", response);
  } catch (error) {
    console.log("error", error);
  }
  return response;
};
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Quko is not an array
try this:

```
const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  console.log("state", state.question.questions.response);
  return {
    user: state.auth.user,
    Quko: state.question.questions.response?.gettAllQuestions,
  };
};
```

and edit this line of your code like this:

```
 async componentDidMount() {
    console.log('this.props.Questions', this.props.Quko);
    await this.props.getAllQuestions(this.props.user._id);
    await this.setState({ questions: this.props.Quko?.map(e=> return e.answer) });
  }
```

Comment: this led me to this errr statement Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {answer}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.

Comment: thats because your array is consist of objects.
if you want to show your answers try this:

  async componentDidMount() {
    console.log('this.props.Questions', this.props.Quko);
    await this.props.getAllQuestions(this.props.user._id);
    await this.setState({ questions: this.props.Quko.map(e=> return e.answer) });
  }

Answer (score 0):

"`this.props.Quko is not iterable`" is happening because the syntax `[...this.props.Quko]` requires this.props.Quko to be an array.

When you log `this.props.Quko`, you're getting an object. If you're hoping to deconstruct the array that's in there, what you want is:

`[...this.props.Quko.gettAllQuestions]`

Comment: ×
Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): this.props.Quko.getAllQuestions is not iterable getting this error

Comment: It looks like your variable is actually called `gettAllQuestions`